# Prove that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{p^{n}} )\cong \mathbb{Z}_{\phi(p^{n})}$ where p is a prime and $\phi(.)$ denotes the euler totient function.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

Can anyone tell me how to prove this?...I was asked to find the number of homomorphims from $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{121} )$ to $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_{25} )$ .
In the solution they used the result that I asked in the title and then calculated the number of homomorphims  from $\mathbb{Z}_{110}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ which is easy enough to do as it is just the gcd(20,110)=10 But how so I prove the above theorem?.

Comment: One thing, if $p=2,n=3$ this isn't true, for instance.  So you need to say something about $p$.  My point is that, for example, the automorphism group of $\Bbb Z_8$ is the Klein four group (not cyclic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An automorphism of $\Bbb Z_n$ is determined by sending a generator, say $1$, to a  generator, which is to say to $k$ such that $(k,n)=1$.  We pretty easily get the nice result that $\rm{Aut}(\Bbb Z_n)\cong\Bbb Z_n^\times$.

(Note that, in particular, when $n=1,2,4,p^\alpha,2p^\alpha$ for $p\gt2$ prime, we get a cyclic automorphism group.  This part is nontrivial.  See for instance I.M. Vinogradov's *Elements of Number Theory*.)

Comment: Sorry for late comment. Can you tell me what does the symbol $Z_{n}^{\times}$ ? I have learnt group theory from books from local bengali publishers...so I am not familiar with all the symbolic notations.I know that $Aut(Z_{n})\cong U_{n}$ . Is this what is meant by $Z_{n}^{\times}$?

Comment: Yes.  I am referring to the group of units.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Can you refer me to a link where I can find a similar result like you said : for n = 1,2,4, $p^{\alpha}$ etc we get cyclic automorphism group ( I assume that since this is true then $U_{n}$ will be cyclic and will be isomorphic to $Z_{n}$) .

Comment: I would guess that any good number theory text would be a good way to go.  Don't have a link for it on the internet off the top of my head.  As I said, it is nontrivial.  But yes, that is precisely when the group of units is cyclic.  Gauss knew it.  Note that when it is true $U_n\cong\Bbb Z_{\varphi(n)}$.  The order of the group of units is always $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: Thanks I found it in wikipedia.